# Group and display MYSQL rows by day?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a **MYSQL** database and I'm using **PHP**.

My table structure looks like this:

```
id      title      date
1       apple      2020-03-10
2       banana     2020-03-10
3       avocado    2020-03-20
4       potato     2020-03-20
5       tomato     2020-03-20
```

And I want to select it and display results using PHP so I get them **grouped by day** like here:

```
2020-03-10
1       apple
2       banana

2020-03-20
3       avocado
4       potato
5       tomato
```

What is the best way to achieve that?

I read every relevant answer here but they differ a lot.

Comment: SQL statements return rows, not headings and data items underneath. Best just 'ORDER BY `date`' and handle the formatting and grouping in PHP.

Comment: Iterate over the return rows and store the current date in a variable. At start of iteration check "current date" against row date if they match don't output, if they don't output it.

Comment: You have to make 2 queries, first time to get all rows `group by date` and next create a loop and make a second query inside the loop to fetch all records related to this date.

Comment: @SergheiLeonenco That a lot more work than necessary.

Comment: Any way he will probably will use prepared statements so, i do not see any problem with this amount of data to sort this way. and you suggestion works as well, i can't disagree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just `order by` the date and then you can use the PHP to apply the appropriate headers like this:

```
$rows = array(array('date' => '2020-03-10', 'title' => 'bannana'), array('date' => '2020-03-10', 'title' => 'orange'),array('date' => '2020-03-11', 'title' => 'kiwi'),array('date' => '2020-03-12', 'title' => 'ice cream!'),);
$previous = '';
foreach($rows as $row) {
    if($row['date'] != $previous) {
        echo $row['date'] . PHP_EOL;
    }
    echo $row['title'] . PHP_EOL;
    $previous = $row['date'];
}
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/WbPgK

> 2020-03-10
>   bannana
>   orange
>   2020-03-11
>   kiwi
>   2020-03-12
>   ice cream!

Comment: Thank you very much! It works like a charm.